# echo list of tags associated with a post in a data-category tag

Tags: php, wordpress, tags

I'm trying to a echo list of tags associated with a post in a data-category tag inside a div. At the moment my code outputs nothing in the tag. i've also had it where it outputs the word 'Array'. I need to to display as 'tag1 tag2 etc'

Here is how i currently have my code set up inside the if have posts loop...

getting the values...

```
    $post_tag = wp_get_post_tags( $post_id, $args );
```

echoing the values...

```
        <div data-category="<?php foreach($post_tag as $tag){ echo $tag; } ?>">
```

Here's the full code...

```
    <?php $layout = get_post_type(); ?>

    <?

    $slug = get_post( $post )->post_name;
    $post_tag = wp_get_post_tags( $post_id, $args );


    ?>

    <? if ( $layout == 'fullscreenimage' ){ ?>


    <p>layout 1</p>

        <div class="portfolio-item" data-id="<?php echo $slug; ?>" data-category="<?php foreach($post_tag as $tag){ echo $tag; } ?>">

            <h1 class="entry-title"><?php the_title(); ?></h1>

        </div>

    <?php } elseif ( $layout == 'singleimagetext' ) {  ?>

        <p>layout 2</p>

        <div class="portfolio-item" data-id="<?php echo $slug; ?>" data-category="<? //echo $tags; ?>">

            <h1 class="entry-title"><?php the_title(); ?></h1>

        </div>

    <?php } elseif ( $layout == 'casestudy' ) {  ?>

        <p>layout 3</p>

        <div class="portfolio-item" data-id="<?php echo $slug; ?>" data-category="<? //echo $tags; ?>">

            <h1 class="entry-title"><?php the_title(); ?></h1>

        </div>

    <?php } elseif ( $layout == 'gallery' ) {  ?>

        <p>layout 4</p>

        <div class="portfolio-item" data-id="<?php echo $slug; ?>" data-category="<? //echo $tags; ?>">

            <h1 class="entry-title"><?php the_title(); ?></h1>

        </div>


    <?php } ?>

<?php endwhile; ?>

<?php else : ?>

    <h2 class=”center”>Not Found</h2>
    <p class=”center”>Sorry, but you are looking for something that isn’t here.</p>

<?php endif; ?>
<?php /* end my loop */ ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

$tag is an object of std Class according to documentation, in order to get the tag name just try this

```
<div data-category="<?php foreach($post_tag as $tag){ echo $tag->name; } ?>">
```

$tag->name is just getting the stdClass Object property named as name.

This is what the object returns, so you can get other information also like term_id or slug for the URL.

```
 stdClass Object
       (
           [term_id] => 4
           [name] => tag2
           [slug] => tag2
           [term_group] => 0
           [term_taxonomy_id] => 4
           [taxonomy] => post_tag
           [description] => 
           [parent] => 0
           [count] => 7
       )
```

Documentation [wp get post tags](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_post_tags)

Comment: Thanks but this returned nothing. the tags i'm trying to get are custom taxonomies so i don't know if that needs special treatment?

Comment: it just show.. 'data-category' is this what you mean?

Comment: ahh no its not... how do i do a variable dump?

Comment: The above code should work if you have the tags for the post, I don't know what is the issue here.  Place var_dump($post_tag); after $post_tag = wp_get_post_tags( $post_id, $args ); then visit the page and see what output you are getting?

Comment: sorry for delayed response but the output of the var dump is array(0) { }

Answer (score 0):

added a function to functions.php

```
function my_post_terms() {

// Get an array of all taxonomies for this post
$taxonomies = get_taxonomies( '', 'names' );

// Are there any taxonomies to get terms from?
if ( $taxonomies ) {    

    // Call the wp_get_post_terms function to retrieve all terms. It accepts an array of taxonomies as argument. 
    $arr_terms = wp_get_post_terms( get_the_ID(), array_values( $taxonomies ) , array( "fields" => "names" ) );

    // Convert the terms array to a string
    $terms = implode( ' ',$arr_terms );

    // Get out of here
    return $terms;
}
}
```

then added this echo my_post_terms(); in html...

```
<div class="portfolio-item" data-id="<?php echo $slug; ?>" data-category="<?php echo my_post_terms(); ?>">
```